# Unable to install MySQL-python " invalid command 'egg_info' "

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python

I'm getting a weird error after running
    $ pip install mysql-python

Has anyone seen an error like this with "egg_info" being invalid?

I'm running OSX mountain lion

```
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Using download cache from /Users/Marcus/.pip/cache/https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FM%2FMySQL-python%2FMySQL-python-1.2.4.zip
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
Extracting in /var/folders/ss/nxvs3w690xqbpvr_l0v31mrw0000gn/T/tmpg_MvY6
Now working in /var/folders/ss/nxvs3w690xqbpvr_l0v31mrw0000gn/T/tmpg_MvY6/distribute-0.6.28
Building a Distribute egg in /Users/Marcus/sites/venv/build/MySQL-python
/Users/Marcus/sites/venv/build/MySQL-python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg
usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

error: invalid command 'egg_info'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz

Extracting in /var/folders/ss/nxvs3w690xqbpvr_l0v31mrw0000gn/T/tmpg_MvY6

Now working in /var/folders/ss/nxvs3w690xqbpvr_l0v31mrw0000gn/T/tmpg_MvY6/distribute-0.6.28

Building a Distribute egg in /Users/Marcus/sites/venv/build/MySQL-python

/Users/Marcus/sites/venv/build/MySQL-python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg

usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

   or: -c --help-commands

   or: -c cmd --help



 error: invalid command 'egg_info'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/Marcus/sites/venv/build/MySQL-python
Storing complete log in /Users/Marcus/.pip/pip.log
```

Thanks

--- I'm getting this same error when I run 
    $ pip install django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need distribute package which is now inside setuptools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: This worked in my case. Strange because I thought I had latest setuptools (installed via ez_setup.py) but when I ran this, pip said I had distribute 0.6.38 rather than the most recent, 0.7.3.